# Efficiently generating a UTC timestamp

Tags: c++

I need to generate UTC timestamps in string format quite often (several times a second), and the code I have for it is inefficient.
Is there a faster way than the one I'm using? It can be assumed that the program will not be running across day boundaries.

```
void GenerateUTCTimestamp(std::string& out)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    tm* utc = gmtime(&tnow);

    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << std::setfill('0');
    ss << std::setw(4) << utc->tm_year + 1900;      // Year
    ss << std::setw(2) << utc->tm_mon + 1;          // Month
    ss << std::setw(2) << utc->tm_mday;             // Day
    ss << '-';
    ss << std::setw(2) << utc->tm_hour << ':';      // Hours
    ss << std::setw(2) << utc->tm_min << ':';       // Minutes
    ss << std::setw(2) << utc->tm_sec;              // Seconds

    out = ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Please do not post links to code, post code itself.

Comment: "Inefficient" code that runs several times a second must be really inefficient to make a noticeable difference. Did you profile to see if "inefficiency" of this particular code fragment reduces performance to unacceptable levels?

Comment: Did you measure the time required for your function? Is it really "too slow" ? I expect the slowness of your implementation will not be noticeable for a function called "several" times a second

Comment: Links to code are not acceptable here. 'Several times a second' is not 'quite often'. A tenth of a second is an eon in computing. You don't have any need to make this startlingly efficient.

Comment: Code is now in the question. This code is part of a real-time application which needs to push out these updates as fast as possible. Profiling shows that a large chunk of the time from the calling function is spent here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have trouble finding faster code than this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

void
stamp(char* s, int i)
{
    do
    {
        *s-- = char(i % 10) + '0';
        i /= 10;
    } while (i > 0);
}

void GenerateUTCTimestamp(std::string& out)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using days = duration<int, ratio<86400>>;
    auto now = time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto today = time_point_cast<days>(now);
    auto s = now - today;

    // y-m-d
    auto z = today.time_since_epoch().count() + 719468;
    const auto era = 5;
    const auto doe = z - era * 146097;
    const auto yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;
    const auto y = yoe + era * 400;
    const auto doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);
    auto m = (5*doy + 2)/153;
    const auto d = doy - (153*m+2)/5 + 1;
    m = m + (m < 10 ? 3 : -9);

    // h:M:s
    const auto h = duration_cast<hours>(s);
    s -= h;
    const auto M = duration_cast<minutes>(s);
    s -= M;

    // format yyyymmdd-hh:MM:ss
    out = "00000000-00:00:00";
    stamp(&out[3], y);
    stamp(&out[5], m);
    stamp(&out[7], d);
    stamp(&out[10], h.count());
    stamp(&out[13], M.count());
    stamp(&out[16], s.count());
}
```

- This code uses the public domain algorithm `civil_from_days` from here:

  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days

  where you can find an in-depth explanation of that algorithm.
- The number of branches in the code is minimized, and the code size itself is minimized.
- The use of general purpose (and convenient) streams are entirely avoided, opting instead for a bare-bones integer-to-char algorithm that doesn't  deal with localization, traits, wide characters, custom widths or alignments or even negative values.
- Except for the first call, memory allocation is completely avoided by reusing and formatting directly into `out`.
- This code *does* *have* a limited range of validity:  2000-03-01 to 2400-02-29.  If you need to make this code valid for points in time outside this range, change the computation of `era` to:

  `const auto era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;`

I put this code in a loop of 1000 calls (with the same `string`), timed it, and averaged the time over all the calls.

On my machine (macOS, clang, libc++, -O3), the original code takes about 3.9µs and the optimized code takes about 150ns (about 25X faster).

Then for grins, I implemented `GenerateUTCTimestamp` using [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to see how it fared in the timing test.  It clearly wins the ease of use test (imho):

```
#include "date.h"

void GenerateUTCTimestamp(std::string& out)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    out = format("%Y%m%d-%T", time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now()));
}
```

It clocked in at 2.5µs, 50% faster than the thread-unsafe C API, but plenty slower than the optimized code.  There's a performance penalty for the flexibility of a general purpose tool.

The date library uses the same calendrical algorithm as the optimized tool (except for using the generalized `era`), but formats into a `stringstream` like the original code.  It also of course has to parse the formatting string.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get why the kneejerk reaction on this site for optimization problems is to just say that there is no need for optimization. These same people would tell Usain Bolt that he doesn't need to shave a millisecond off his time

Comment: If Usain Bolt was spending hours every day trying to figure out how to floss his teeth more quickly in the morning, they'd tell him not to worry about flossing so much, but rather spend that time improving the skills that will help him be a faster runner.